# sphinxsearch does not return me content and title fields

Tags: sphinx

I am using sphinx search with document table. I want to fetch all the fields but it doesn't return me all the fields. Please check my config file and let me know where to make change? using test index

table : documents

Fields: id, group_id, group_id2, date_added, content, title

```
mysql> select * from test1 where match ('my document');
    +------+----------+------------+
    | id   | group_id | date_added |
    +------+----------+------------+
    |    1 |        1 | 1461672351 |
    |    2 |        1 | 1461672351 |
    +------+----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 

source src1
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = india@123
    sql_db          = test
    sql_port        = 3306

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
        FROM documents



    sql_attr_uint       = group_id

    sql_attr_timestamp  = date_added
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
    sql_query_info        = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$id

}

source src1throttled : src1
{
    sql_ranged_throttle = 100
}
index test1
{
    source          = src1
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1
    docinfo         = extern
    dict            = keywords
    mlock           = 0 
    morphology      = none
    min_word_len    = 1
    html_strip      = 0
}
index test1stemmed : test1
{
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1stemmed
    morphology      = stem_en
}
index dist1
{
    type            = distributed
    local           = test1
    local           = test1stemmed
    agent           = localhost:9313:remote1
    agent           = localhost:9314:remote2,remote3
    agent_connect_timeout   = 1000
    agent_query_timeout     = 3000
}
index rt
{
    type            = rt
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/rt
    rt_field        = title
    rt_field        = content
    rt_attr_uint        = gid
}
indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 128M
}

searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    client_timeout      = 300
    max_children        = 30
    persistent_connections_limit    = 30
    pid_file        = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    mva_updates_pool    = 1M
    max_packet_size     = 8M
    max_filters     = 256
    max_filter_values   = 4096
    max_batch_queries   = 32
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
}
common
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. sphinx does not 'store' **Fields**. They can't be returned.

Sphinx 'indexes' the fields, but in its internal Inverse-Index format.

... to get data back out of sphinx - use **Attributes**. In your example index, you've made `group_id` and `date_added` as attributes via the `sql_attr_*`directives.

`sql_field_string` could be useful, as it makes a column BOTH a Field, AND a string attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I play a lot with Sphinxsearch and I get same result (no title, content).

If you add this rows to the config file, the `SELECT * FROM table1;` query will return the `title` and `content` fields, too:

```
sql_field_string        = title
sql_field_string        = content
```